# User Auth in Meteor using an external API

Tags: meteor

I am building a Meteor app that uses my website login API (built in `php`) to check if a user is on my website database or not. So using meteor `HTTP.post` I send user email and password as `params`, and my website API returns a json with a **success** or **failure** message, and that is it.

What I am not being able to do is to, as according to this success message, "login" the user on my Meteor app **without** creating/checking `Users` collection from `accounts`.

So it should be: return success? You are logged in. No `users.insert`, nor anything like that. Is it possible to be done?

To make this API call, I have created a method, activated here:

```
Meteor.call('loginUser', userData, function(error, result){
    if(error)
        console.log(error.reason);
    else(console.log(result)) 

    if (result.status == 'ok') {
        Session.set('loginStatus', 'loggedUser');
        Router.go('/');
    }
});
```

I am using this `Session.set` only to simulate what I am expecting to happen. But using Session is surelly not the best option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `Accounts.createUser()`

http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_createuser

On client, it will login the user automatically.

Comment: He ask for an external login (PHP API), not on `meteor-account`